# Two values showing 0.66 correlation but graphs are totally different

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
A       B
1.8880  298.0
1.7604  380.0
1.5712  376.0
1.4029  381.0
1.0728  321.0
1.7830  266.0
1.4372  341.0
1.4500  372.0
2.0713  421.0
1.7357  402.0
1.8661  407.0
1.5329  340.0
1.7495  449.0
2.0789  438.0
1.5331  450.0
1.6800  449.0
2.1819  402.0
2.3827  358.0
2.2852  384.0
2.1007  392.0
1.7085  410.0
2.0433  476.0
2.9753  463.0
2.6881  532.0
2.6379  454.0
2.0774  538.0
2.7963  419.0
2.8351  488.0
2.7512  662.0
2.3574  555.0
2.7607  511.0
2.2983  572.0
2.3762  562.0
2.5631  582.0
2.3664  679.0
2.0931  518.0
2.5114  484.0
0.0000  335.0
0.0000  342.0
0.0000  300.0
0.0000  314.0
0.0000  321.0
```

I calculate the correlation using:

```
df.corr().loc['A','B']
# 0.6650269816367731
```

When I plot the graphs:

```
sns.lineplot(data=df[['A','B']])
```

I get:

[image]

How does this have such a high correlation when the graph is totally different?

**EDIT**

When I scale the data like so:

```
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(df[all_dimensions_2]), columns=df[all_dimensions_2].columns)
df_scaled = pd.concat([df[['datestamp','device','country_code']],df_scaled],axis=1)
sns.lineplot(data=df_scaled[(df_scaled['country_code']=='PT')&(df_scaled['device']=='desktop')][['A','B']])
```

I get:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The data columns have totally different value ranges. If you scale the data for example using a MinMaxScaler you can see that they do correlate.

[Line plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYk56.png)

Code to scale data and create plot:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(df), columns=df.columns)
df_scaled.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, can I somehow `fit_transform` the entire dataframe in columns that I want rather than using two lines?

Comment: Thanks again, for some reason I get a different plot than yours, any idea why? Edited my question.